# SeeTest - Element not clicked

Tags: c#, android, selenium, seetest

I am new to mobile automation(using SeeTest) and tried to automate Gmail account on mobile browser. There is a "Switch account" element, which is captured while recording. But while execution, the driver is unable to find the element. What needs to be checked/done to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The element is an image, but I recorded as Native recording. On selecting, "Image and Text", the click event was successful.